# Notification shows up in android emulator but not on physical device

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, push-notification, notifications

I have set a timely notification of 30 minutes using JobScheduler, my app shows the notification in Android Emulator(Pixel 3 API 29 Q-10) after 30 minutes but not on my physical device(Samsung S8 Android 9 Pie).
The weird thing is the same notification shows up when I open the app after 30 minutes.
Are there any restrictions in android?

I have tried so far:

- Running app in physical device using USB debugger mode, no errors.
- Building the APK and installing it in the device separately

Comment: Without seeing your code no one can help you out you need to show some code to see what did you do wrong

Comment: Hey, please provide [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Refer to this answer, 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64419687/13266897

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that, If the phone is in power saver mode or any battery optimized mode the notifications won't show up. Turning off power saver mode worked for me.