# Labels appear in Android emulator but not on physical device

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, android-emulator

I created a navigation sidebar app with Xamarin.Forms, and before I had even made any changes to the project, I noticed something was wrong. When I launch the Pixel 2 emulator on my computer, I see the following *correct* view.

[Emulator picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOfzc.png)

However, when I either sent the APK or attached it to my computer and debugged the program I noticed that the labels were not appearing, as seen below from a screenshot on my OnePlus 8T + 5G (Android 11).

[Phone screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPdhS.jpg)

There are obviously more than a few differences between my phone and the emulator, but under most circumstances this should be the same across all devices and the app *does* load other elements (like buttons and images) correctly. What's going on here?

> **Things I've tried**
>
> - Searching for other posts, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66901545/notification-shows-up-in-android-emulator-but-not-on-physical-device), that show different results on the emulator vs. phone. No luck.
> - Changing between Debug/Release and changing APK preferences to avoid code shrinking and possible loss of data. No luck.

Here's the code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Car_Scan.Views.BrowsePage"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Car_Scan.ViewModels"
             Title="{Binding Title}">
    
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:AboutViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Color x:Key="Accent">#96d1ff</Color>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Accent}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Fill">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
                <ContentView Padding="0,40,0,40" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Image Source="xamarin_logo.png" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="64" />
                </ContentView>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
        <ScrollView Grid.Row="1">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="30,24,30,24" Spacing="10">
                <Label Text="Start developing now" FontSize="Title"/>
                <Label Text="Make changes to your XAML file and save to see your UI update in the running app with XAML Hot Reload. Give it a try!" FontSize="16" Padding="0,0,0,0"/>
                <Label FontSize="16" Padding="0,24,0,0">
                    <Label.FormattedText>
                        <FormattedString>
                            <FormattedString.Spans>
                                <Span Text="Learn more at "/>
                                <Span Text="https://aka.ms/xamarin-quickstart" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                            </FormattedString.Spans>
                        </FormattedString>
                    </Label.FormattedText>
                </Label>
                <Button Margin="0,10,0,0" Text="Learn more"
                        Command="{Binding OpenWebCommand}"
                        BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
                        TextColor="White" />
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I am having a very similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.  I was able to reproduce by creating a new Xamarin.Forms project and running it as-is.  On my phone the text is not visible but when ran on an emulator it is.  After trying several different things, I realized my phone was set to Dark Mode.  I turned to Light Mode and it worked.  I am still not sure what exactly it is about Dark Mode that is making this happen, because I have had my phone set to Dark Mode for a long time now.  I found [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/265bf78c-1aa5-4669-bb1a-72f4a8555abc/best-approach-to-handle-dark-theme?forum=xamarinforms)  that I am going to try to implement to see if it allows me to switch between light and dark mode seamlessly.
Hope that's helpful

Comment: This solved my problem too. I wonder if there is an easier solution for this rather than implementing dark mode.

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the `TextColor` Property to a color. like this:

```
<Label Text="Start developing now" FontSize="Title" TextColor="Black"/>
                                                    ^ this
```